# Spring Hibernate connecting to AWS RDS error

Tags: spring, hibernate, amazon-web-services

I am able to run my web application when I point to my local database:

Server version: 5.6.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

```
2015-10-10 13:37:20.598  INFO 2872 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProce
ssors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-10 13:37:20.657  INFO 2872 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAd
visor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-10 13:37:22.419  INFO 2872 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-10-10 13:37:23.022  INFO 2872 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-10-10 13:37:23.025  INFO 2872 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2015-10-10 13:37:23.320  INFO 2872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-10-10 13:37:23.321  INFO 2872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11366 ms
2015-10-10 13:37:27.384  INFO 2872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2015-10-10 13:37:28.649  INFO 2872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegratio
nFilter@28ba6f1f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4d9d07dd, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6ea013e0, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@695c931a, org.springframework.security.web.authenti
cation.logout.LogoutFilter@2243a064, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@288989d8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2b027994, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContext
HolderAwareRequestFilter@69764da4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4c99f499, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@484a49a7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@46e34c
8f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@f2c41d9]
2015-10-10 13:37:29.010  INFO 2872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-10-10 13:37:29.039  INFO 2872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-10-10 13:37:29.041  INFO 2872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-10-10 13:37:29.041  INFO 2872 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2015-10-10 13:37:30.042  INFO 2872 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-10-10 13:37:30.117  INFO 2872 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2015-10-10 13:37:30.384  INFO 2872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
2015-10-10 13:37:30.404  INFO 2872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-10-10 13:37:30.408  INFO 2872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-10-10 13:37:31.228  INFO 2872 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-10-10 13:37:31.426  INFO 2872 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2015-10-10 13:37:31.949  INFO 2872 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

I am able to access my 2 AWS RDS databases from my desktop using Hedidi. The databases have different versions:

- MySQL 5.6.23
- MySQL 5.1.73a

But when I point to my database and run again I get the follow exception:

```
2015-10-10 13:42:40.605  INFO 512 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-10-10 13:42:41.142  INFO 512 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-10-10 13:42:41.146  INFO 512 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2015-10-10 13:42:41.656  INFO 512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-10-10 13:42:41.657  INFO 512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10478 ms
2015-10-10 13:42:46.992  INFO 512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2015-10-10 13:42:48.872  INFO 512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegration
Filter@390fc764, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@69bdf685, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@71a70302, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@754e07d4, org.springframework.security.web.authentic
ation.logout.LogoutFilter@2eac817e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@46dea8a1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4c69ba89, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextH
olderAwareRequestFilter@36ac2a3f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@aa7fb44, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@ac2d960, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@54bfdd50,
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1c99fb02]
2015-10-10 13:42:49.358  INFO 512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-10-10 13:42:49.398  INFO 512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-10-10 13:42:49.399  INFO 512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-10-10 13:42:49.399  INFO 512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2015-10-10 13:42:50.449  INFO 512 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-10-10 13:42:50.546  INFO 512 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2015-10-10 13:42:50.913  INFO 512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
2015-10-10 13:42:50.941  INFO 512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-10-10 13:42:50.945  INFO 512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-10-10 13:42:51.855  INFO 512 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-10-10 13:42:52.080  WARN 512 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2015-10-10 13:42:52.095  WARN 512 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exc
eption is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at configuration.Application.main(Application.java:12)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:205)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Here is the only thing I change:

```
#database.driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#database.driverManagerDataSource.setUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/question_time_server
#database.driverManagerDataSource.setUsername=root
#database.driverManagerDataSource.setPassword=

database.driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.driverManagerDataSource.setUrl=jdbc:mysql://csrwot1tk8jt.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mobilequestionnaire
database.driverManagerDataSource.setUsername=????
database.driverManagerDataSource.setPassword=????
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.1.1'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.0.RELEASE'

    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'


jar {
    baseName = 'MobileQuestionnaire'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.+")
    compile("org.webjars:bootstrap:3.0.3")
    compile("org.webjars:jquery:2.0.3-1")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.7.RELEASE")

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}
```

I thought it would be a simple matter of just pointing from my local to AWS RDS. But it's not...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the dbinstance before the hash number:

```
jdbc:mysql://<dbinstance>.csrwot1tk8jt.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mobilequestionnaire
```

I connect to RDS like this (using java config):

```
// dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://something.cfscmuq3e7df.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/database");
```

Comment: Thanks man, the name of the database is the same as the dbinstance. confused me.

Comment: on the RDS configuration it's shown  DB name as default to ebdb, in case  , is the db instance  correspondent to database name ?

Answer (score 0):

Also, please check that the elastic beanstalk is configured with the amazon RDS. I no issues building and deploying locally, with my application pointing to the AWS RDS, but once I tried to deploy on the aws elastic beanstalk, i had this issue.

Please look here for a description of how to do it:
[Adding an Amazon RDS Database to Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html)